# No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `=='

Tags: haskell, ghci

In the following Haskell code:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

data EXP a = Empty | Symbol a
           deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

test :: (Ord a) => EXP a -> [[a]]

test Empty = []
test (Symbol x) = [[x]]

value = (test Empty) == []
```

I get the following error:

```
problem.hs:12:10:
    No instance for (Ord a0) arising from a use of `test'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Ord a => Ord (EXP a) -- Defined at problem.hs:5:32
      instance Integral a => Ord (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Ord GeneralCategory -- Defined in `Data.Char'
      ...plus 26 others
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `(test Empty)'
    In the expression: (test Empty) == []
    In an equation for `value': value = (test Empty) == []

problem.hs:12:22:
    No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of `=='
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Eq a => Eq (EXP a) -- Defined at problem.hs:5:28
      instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Eq GeneralCategory -- Defined in `Data.Char'
      ...plus 26 others
    In the expression: (test Empty) == []
    In an equation for `value': value = (test Empty) == []
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

But if I remove the last line, so the code is:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

data EXP a = Empty | Symbol a
           deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

test :: (Ord a) => EXP a -> [[a]]

test Empty = []
test (Symbol x) = [[x]]
```

I can do the following in the interactive prompt, without error:

```
Prelude> :l problem.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( problem.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> test Empty == []
True
*Main>
```

Why do I get an error when the == check is in the source file, but not when it's in the interactive prompt?

Comment: Monomorphism restriction lift in GHCi. (yet again)

Comment: Hi Bartek, can you expand a little on what that means, or give a resource that would help me understand?

Comment: [Monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) is disabled in GHCi by default. This keeps reappearing on SO, with the similar ambiguity message (hence "yet again").

Comment: This is *not* about the monomorphism restriction being lifted. It's about GHCi having extended default rules, as bheklilr's answer explains correctly. The monomorphism restriction causes the definition in the source file to fail, but it doesn't apply to the GHCi input, as it's not a let binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to get `value` to compile is a local type signature

```
value = (test Empty :: [[()]]) == []
```

Or better yet, use `null`:

```
value = null $ test Empty
```

This is because the type of `test` is

```
test :: EXP a -> [[a]]
```

And the type of `value` is just `Bool`.  The compiler has no way to guess exactly what `Eq` instance to use inside of `value`, it can't be inferred from the context.  In general whenever you see `== []`, you should replace this with the `null` function since this avoids the `Eq` constraint.

It works in GHCi because when you type in `(test Empty) == []`, GHCi's extended defaulting rules will automatically pick `()` for the ambiguous `a` type.

Comment: do you know why GHCi does that? what are the practical reasons for wanting that different behavior?

Comment: @Cam Actually, the practical reason is situations like this.  Interactive development is not meant to be as formal as your finished application, so you can think of it as a relaxation of the type checking rules so that you don't have to give explicit types all the time.  For example, GHCi picks `IO` as its default instance for `Monad`, it picks `Double` for `Floating`, `Integer` for `Integral`, and more.  It's just there to help reduce the number of expressions that need explicit signatures.  It does trip a lot of people up, though, I'm not sure how much of a net positive this feature is.

Comment: Nice explanation! I always forgot how useful `()` is in these scenarios!

Answer (score 1):

Just explicitly annotate it with type:

```
value = test Empty == ([] :: [[Int]])
```

The type of `[]` can be anything: `[Int]` or `[Float]` or `[[Int]]`. The compiler is not able to figure it out because even `Exp` is polymorphic. If your function was like this you wouldn't have to explicitly annotate:

```
test :: EXP Int -> [[Int]]
test Empty = []
test (Symbol x) = [[x]]

value = test Empty == []
```

Or even if you are ready to give it hints like this:

```
value :: [[Int]]
value = (test Empty)

value2 = value == []
```

That said, instead of using `Int`, use `()` for annotating as @bheklir has done. That is a better approach of tagging type to remove ambiguity for the compiler.